# How can I cast a char to an unsigned int?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a char array that is really used as a byte array and not for storing text. In the array, there are two specific bytes that represent a numeric value that I need to store into an unsigned int value.  The code below explains the setup.

```
char* bytes = bytes[2];
bytes[0] = 0x0C; // For the sake of this example, I'm 
bytes[1] = 0x88; // assigning random values to the char array.

unsigned int val = ???; // This needs to be the actual numeric 
                        // value of the two bytes in the char array.  
                        // In other words, the value should equal 0x0C88;
```

I can not figure out how to do this.  I would assume it would involve some casting and recasting of the pointers, but I can not get this to work.  How can I accomplish my end goal?

**UPDATE**

Thank you Martin B for the quick response, however this doesn't work.  Specifically, in my case the two bytes are `0x00` and `0xbc`.  Obviously what I want is `0x000000bc`.  But what I'm getting in my unsigned int is `0xffffffbc`.

The code that was posted by Martin was my actual, original code and works fine so long as all of the bytes are less than 128 (.i.e. positive signed char values.)

Comment: You wouldn't want to use pointers, since `unsigned int` is unlikely to be the same size as `char[2]`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
unsigned int val = (unsigned char)bytes[0] << CHAR_BIT | (unsigned char)bytes[1];
```

This if `sizeof(unsigned int) >= 2 * sizeof(unsigned char)` (not something guaranteed by the C standard)

Now... The interesting things here is surely the order of operators (in many years still I can remember only `+, -, * and /`... Shame on me :-), so I always put as many brackets I can). `[]` is king. Second is the `(cast)`. Third is the `<<` and fourth is the `|` (if you use the `+` instead of the `|`, remember that `+` is more importan than `<<` so you'll need brakets)

We don't need to upcast to `(unsigned integer)` the two `(unsigned char)` because there is the [integral promotion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc9te331.aspx) that will do it for us for one, and for the other it should be an automatic [Arithmetic Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx).

I'll add that if you want less headaches:

```
unsigned int val = (unsigned char)bytes[0] << CHAR_BIT;
val |= (unsigned char)bytes[1];
```

Comment: +1: The only answer so far that does it properly.  The cast to `unsigned int` is unnecessary, though.

Comment: On that last line, `val |= ...` might be faster.

Comment: Your first line of code has solved the problem.  However, I've also tried the last snippet before posting this question.  That was one "solution" that simply didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int val = (unsigned char) bytes[0]<<8 | (unsigned char) bytes[1];
```

Comment: @MooingDuck I indeed missed casting, but << has higher precedence than |, so no paranthesis are need in my version.

Answer (score 2):

The byte ordering depends on the endianness of your processor.  You can do this, which will work on big or little endian machines.  (without ntohs it will work on big-endian):

```
unsigned int val = ntohs(*(uint16_t*)bytes)
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, since ntohs will read in too many bytes.

Comment: @MooingDuck, it will work, ntohs is for 16-bit values.  ntohl is for 32-bits

Comment: oh, correct.  However, `*(unsigned int*)bytes` will read in too many bytes.

Comment: Better, but it's possible that this will have alignment problems.  Wait, I don't think this question has anything to do with endian-ness...

Comment: You have to worry about endianness if you map a 16-bit pointer to it.  If you do *(uint16_t*) on little endian, val == 0x880C.  On big-endian, val == 0xC88.  Alignment point is true, but extremely hard to find a processor these days that can't do unaligned accesses, even in the embedded world.

Comment: @TJD: It's not that difficult.  It's fairly common for DSP ISAs to not support unaligned accesses, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int val = bytes[0] << 8 + bytes[1];
```

Comment: I couldn't resist it... It was so black & white :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this will invoke integer overflow (if `char` is `signed` by default) when the msb of `bytes[0]` is set.

Comment: I'll add that there is a half km long of warnings. Nowhere in the standard it's written that a byte is only 8 bit :-)

Comment: @xanatos, didn't realise `` and 4spaces formatted code differently

Comment: You need parentheses around `<<` operation and this won't work with negative values.

Comment: @Banthar: You don't *need* the parentheses, although it's probably advisable from a readability point of view.

Comment: In fact, I retract my earlier comment!  It simply won't work properly if `char` is `signed`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way to go about it than relying on pointer aliasing:

```
union {unsigned asInt; char asChars[2];} conversion;
conversion.asInt = 0;
conversion.asChars[0] = 0x0C;
conversion.asChars[1] = 0x88;
unsigned val = conversion.asInt;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this still relies on type aliasing.

Comment: @MooingDuck: C99 allows type-punning through unions - a footnote which makes this explicit was added to section 6.5.2.3 with TC3 in 2007; however, Chuck's code assumes little-endian byte order - shifting is the portable solution

Comment: @Christoph: It's illegal in C++, my mistake.  I can't remove my -1 until it's edited :(

Comment: @MooingDuck: added a missing semicolon, so fire away ;)