# Converting a char* to unsigned int in C safely?

Tags: c, string, pointers, glibc

I wrote a pretty simple function to perform this conversion in C.  Is it perfectly safe? if not, what are the other ways?

***EDIT:***
I rewrote the function to add more effective error checks.

```
#define UNLESS(x) if (!(x))

int char_to_uint(const char *str, unsigned int* res)
{    
    /* return 0 if str is NULL */
    if (!str){
        return 0;
    }

    char *buff_temp;
    long long_str;

    /* we set up errno to 0 before */
    errno = 0;

    long_str = strtol(str, &buff_temp, 10); 

    /* some error and boundaries checks */
    if (buff_temp == str || *buff_temp != '\0' || long_str < 0){
        return 0; 
    }

    /* errno != 0 = an error occured */
    if ((long_str == 0 && errno != 0) || errno == ERANGE){
        return 0;
    }

    /* if UINT_MAX < ULONG_MAX so we check for overflow */
    UNLESS(UINT_MAX == ULONG_MAX){
        if (long_str > UINT_MAX) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            /* 0xFFFFFFFF : real UINT_MAX */
            if(long_str > 0xFFFFFFFF){ 
                return 0;
            } 
        }  
    }

    /* after that, the cast is safe */
    *res = (unsigned int)long_str;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Returning 0 for an invalid string does not seem useful.  If you want to treat `"foo"` as an error, a caller of your function cannot distinguish it from the string`"0"`.  For each string, your function returns 0.

Comment: There are plenty of machines where UINT_MAX and ULONG_MAX are the same, so that test of yours for overflow may not do what you want.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks you. But we must check the value with `UINT_MAX` before casting, no ?

Comment: I'm agree for 0 as return error value.. What to return instead ?

Comment: Converting a string to an integer, and checking for all possible errors, can be surprisingly tricky, even when you have `strtol` do most of the work for you.  See [Correct usage of strtol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123).

Comment: You want to convert to an unsigned integer, why do you use `strtol` unstead of `strtoul`?

Comment: If `int` and `long` have the same size, you want to make sure you listen to strto(u)l if it tells you the input number was too big.  If `int` is smaller than `long`, you additionally want a test like the one you showed in your question, before you cast.  So you might want to conditionally compile that test with `#if ULONG_MAX > UINT_MAX`.

Comment: it would make more sense to return 0 on failure, 1 on success, and use a pointer assignment instead of returning the converted integer.

Comment: I have added some error checks and modified the function adding an unsigned int pointer as argument and a coherent return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
unsigned int val = (unsigned char)bytes[0] << CHAR_BIT;
val |= (unsigned char)bytes[1];
```

from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7893232/14525990)

Comment: Really interesting, less tricky and less error prone.